# How to get version_id of page in wiki with Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-wiki

With Gitlab API it is currently possible to get a specific page of the wiki, and to edit it.

With UI, when you click on a page, you can view its history and see various truncated commit hash depending on version. Is it possible to get these hash with API? Can't find anything in documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using API.
The solution I used was to use the fact that the wiki is a git repo. So I cloned the wiki repo and got last relevant commit ID with `git log -n1 --format="%H" My-page.md`

Answer (score 1):

Wiki API is there to access the wiki at its current state. Other than that you can use [Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html) to see wiki events:

```
https GET "https://gitlab.url/api/v4/projects/123456/events?target_type=wiki" "PRIVATE-TOKEN: your_private_token"
```

where `gitlab.url` is your GitLab instance URL, `123456` is the project ID and `your_private_token` is your private token

Comment: Thanks! This is useful information, even if not really what I need. From this I get an id, which I guess is an event id. But it is not related to version_id of wiki page so.